# Eloquent triple composite primary key

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to make a database system using Laravel's Eloquent that has the following strategy:

-- Project
------- Stage
------------ Lands

Where each project has many stages, and each stage has many lands. A land can only belong to one stage, and a stage can only belong to one project.

My initial plan was to make the `lands` table reference `stages` table, and, in turn, that stage table will reference its parenting "project".
This was working. However, this setup was not suitable because The system needs each stage and land id need to start from 1. For example (**Project 1** has Stage 1, Stage 2. Each stage has its own Land 1, Land 2, etc - **Project 2** has *stage 1* -> land 1, land 2, etc), but the previous setup will make the IDs of `stages` and `lands`  cumulative not unique to each parenting project.

**What I tried to do**

I tried combining the primary keys as the following:

projects migration:

```
        Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id("project_id");
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('region');
            $table->double('area');
            $table->date('start_date')->nullable();
            $table->date('end_date')->nullable();
        });
```

stages migration:

```
        Schema::create('stages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('stage_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('project_id');
            $table->foreign('project_id')->references('project_id')->on('projects')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->primary(array('project_id', 'stage_id'), 'project_stage_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->double('area');
            $table->date('start_date')->nullable();
            $table->date('end_date')->nullable();
        });
```

lands migration:

```
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('land_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('stage_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('project_id');
            $table->foreign('stage_id')->references('stage_id')->on('stages')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('project_id')->references('project_id')->on('stages')->onDelete('cascade');
            
            $table->primary(array('project_id', 'stage_id', 'land_id'), 'land_id');
            $table->date('cultivation_date');
```

after executing the migration, I'm getting this error:

```
  SQLSTATE[42830]: Invalid foreign key: 7 ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "stages" (SQL: alter table "lands" add constraint "lands_stage_id_foreign" foreign key ("stage_id") references "stages" ("stage_id") on delete cascade)
```

I have tested the stage-project relationship on its own and it works as expected, however, I'm unable to integrate the unique stage-project key into the "lands" table.

Comment: "The system needs each stage and land id need to start from 1". Does your system need to query all "stage 1" of all projects often ?

Comment: Yes, the pre-existing undigitized system deals with each stage as its own mini-project with its own data (that may or may not have things in common with other stages). Several queries will need to be made on each separate stage @N69S

Comment: Separately. So your new structure will be useless in that regard. Can't you just add a fields "name" or "Order" and name each first project stage "stage 1" or just "1" using your old more cohesive structure ?

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine! This error is caused by the date order of your migration files. Please make sure your `stages` table was created before your `lands` table. Like:

```
2023_02_13_034631_create_stages_table
// AND
2023_02_14_034631_create_lands_table
```

Comment: `stages` migration is indeed executed before the `lands`.
This is Stages: `2023_02_07_161226_create_stages_table`.  and this is `lands` migration name: `2023_02_07_161235_create_lands_table`. I can also see from the artisan that `stages` migration was done successfully. @cengsemihsahin

Comment: Ok, when I look more carefully I can see that: In your lands migration file `$table->id();` and `$table->unsignedBigInteger('land_id');` there is. Which is the primary key? Should you close one? @AhmedDeghady AND can you specify the `->primary()` method for the primary key one. Also in order to work the `foreign` key must be an unsigned big integer with `index()`

Comment: The PK should be `$table->unsignedBigInteger('land_id')`. I have removed `$table->id();` from `lands` table the issue still persists @cengsemihsahin